# For each thing in one CSV check for multiple types of matches in another CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

Sorry if the description is unclear, but I couldn't think of how else to word it.

I have two CSV files:

LocalAdmins.csv -- ColumnA = PC name; ColumnB = username in local admin group

[image: PC names and local admin usernames for each PC]

Exempt.csv -- ColumnA = PC name; ColumnB = username allowed to be a local admin

[image: PC names and allowed local admin usernames for each PC]

What I'm trying to do is loop through LocalAdmins.csv, and for each one check to see if the PC name shows up in Exempt.csv (or matches any defined naming patterns in that file), and if a match is found, check to see if the local admin username for that PC in LocalAdmins.csv shows up in the list of AllowedUsers for that PC in Exempt.csv.

If the username is NOT in the AllowedUsers list, or if the PC name is not in Exempt.csv, then output the entry from LocalAdmins.csv.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$admins = Import-Csv .\LocalAdmins.csv
$exempt = Import-Csv .\Exempt.csv
$violations = ".\Violations.csv"

foreach ($admin in $admins) {
    foreach ($item in $exempt) {
        if ($admin.PC -like $item.PC) {
            if ($admin.Name -notin ($item.AllowedUsers -split ",")) {
                $admin | Export-Csv $violations -Append -NoTypeInformation
            }
        }
        else {
            $admin | Export-Csv $violations -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the nested foreach loop generates duplicates, meaning if there are 3 lines in Exempt.csv then a single entry in LocalAdmins.csv will have 3 duplicate outputs (one for each line in Exempt.csv).  So the output looks like this:

[image: Current output]

When it should look like this:

[image: Desired output]

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the structure of the loops, but I just need some help figuring out what to tweak.  Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i would like to give it a try ... but you posted _PICTURES_ of the two sources. i am not going to type in what you already have as text ... [*frown*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not optimized (unique sort by *any* property should work):

```
$admins = Import-Csv .\LocalAdmins.csv
$exempt = Import-Csv .\Exempt.csv
$violations = ".\Violations.csv"

$(
    foreach ($admin in $admins) {
        foreach ($item in $exempt) {
            if ($admin.PC -like $item.PC) {
                if ($admin.Name -notin ($item.AllowedUsers -split ",")) {
                    $admin
                }
            }
            else {
                $admin
            }
        }
    }
) | Sort-Object -Property PC, Name -Unique  | 
            Export-Csv $violations -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

With better restrictions of the forEach, there shouldn't be duplicates
and no need to Sort -unique.

Getting input from here-strings

```
## Q:\Test\2019\02\05\SO_54523868.ps1
$admins = @'
PC,NAME
XYZlaptop,user6
workstationXYZ,user7
computerABC,user8
ABClaptop,user1
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv # .\LocalAdmins.csv

$exempt = @'
PC,AllowedUsers
*laptop,"user1,user2"
computerXYZ,"user3,user4"
workstation*,"user5"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv # .\Exempt.csv

$violationsFile = ".\Violations.csv"

$violations = foreach ($admin in $admins) {
    $violation = $True
    foreach ($item in ($exempt|Where-Object {$admin.PC -like $_.PC})){
        if ($admin.NAME -in ($item.AllowedUsers -split ',')){
            $violation = $False
        }
    }
    if ($violation){$admin}    
}
$violations
$violations | Export-Csv $violationsFile -NotypeInformation
## with Doug Finke's ImportExcel module  installed, you can directly get the excel file:
#$violations | Export-Excel .\Violatons.xlsx -AutoSize -Show
```